# Breaking Out of Multiple Loops When a Condition is Met Without Using Goto (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

In the method below, I have a two-dimensional array of characters called myarr and a string called code. I go through each character in code using the counter i, and look for a character in myarr that matches code[i]. When I find the character in myarr that matches code[i], I want to exit both of the for loops and the if statement and go back to the beginning of the while loop. The only way I can think of doing this is by using a goto statement. However, using goto is generally discouraged, so I was wondering if there was any other way to achieve this.

```
string decrypt(string code, char myarr[][5])
{
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
int i = 0;
string newstr = "";

while(i<code.length()-1)
{
    //This is where I want to go back to
    if (code[i] != ' ')
    {
        for (r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                if (code[i] = myarr[r][c])
                {
                    newstr += myarr[c][r];
                    i++;
                    //This is where I want to exit
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newstr += " ";
        i++;
    }

}
return newstr;
}
```

Comment: How about simplifying this and making a function out of the complexity you have here ... just return when you are done !

Comment: Don't reinvent `goto`, just use `goto`...

Comment: There's also the possibility of declaring a boolean `bool keep_on = true;` and have each loop condition become `condition && keep_on` if you really want to avoid gotos.

Comment: Using goto, with a well-named label is not something I would frown upon in this case. There are several, more severe style issues with your code though and I frown upon them!

Comment: Could you please let me know what style issues I have? I'm pretty new to programming and would benefit from constructive criticism.

Comment: In no particular order: qualify standard names with `std::`, do not use (what I guess is) `using namespace std;`. Declare variables in the smallest scope possible, *expecially* loop counters such as `r`, `c` and `i`. Do not use C-style arrays, use `std::array`, `std::string` or `std::vector`. Your `while` can be rewritten as a `for` to clarify `i`'s role. Make sure that the inner `if` should indeed perform an assignment, and double its parentheses to signal that it is intended. `newstr` does not need an initializer as `std::string` has a suitable default constructor.

Comment: Lastly, consider posting your finished, working code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you want a thorough review :)

Comment: Unrelated: A couple bugs you might as well fix before you burn too much time on them. `code[i] = myarr[r][c]` almost certainly should be `code[i] == myarr[r][c]`. There is something up with the incrementing of `i`. If `code[i]` doesn't match a character in `myarr`, there is no incrcrement and you have an infinite loop. If every character MUST match at least one value in `myarr`, you can increment once at the bottom of the `while` loop (or make a `for` loop). If not, you have to deal with the infinite loop.

Comment: Also looks like you have an off-by-one bug: `while(i<code.length()-1)` will skip the last character. Nothing inside the loop suggests you want to do this. If the string has ten characters `while(i<code.length())` will inspect characters 0 through 9, all ten characters. The same will happen in the `for` loops. They will range 0 through 3 and leave 4 un-inspected.

Comment: If I may, `(i<code.length()-1)` is also surprisingly dangerous.  The reason being that `code.length() - 1` is an unsigned integer and will typically not be what you'd want if `code.length() == 0`. (you can catch those stealthy sources of bugs with -Wsign-compare on gcc/clang)

Answer (score 1):

You use a flag-ish variabele.

set a boolean to true at the beginning of the while loop.
then when the condition is met, you set it to false.
in every inner loop you also check for that flag being true.

Also. in my opinion this is one of the cases where goto is justified.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do:

```
char decrypthelper(char codech, // returns the substitution character for codech
                   const char myarr[][5]) //const because we aren't changing myarr. 
                                          // This will make sure we don't, and maybe
                                          // the compiler can do something sneaky.
{
    if (codech != ' ')
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) // fixed off by one error
                                    // declare index variable here. No one else needs it
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) // fixed off by one error
            {
                if (codech == myarr[r][c]) // was assignment not compare
                {
                    return myarr[c][r]; // found substitution. Exit
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return ' '; // space... the final frontier
    }
    return '?'; // unknown character
}

string decrypt(string code, char myarr[][5])
{
    string newstr = "";

    for (auto codech: code) // for each character in code
    {
        newstr += decrypthelper(codech, myarr); // add substitution character
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

I tried to keep the code recognizable. There are a whole bunch of other tricks you can use to make your job a lot easier, so once you have your program up and running and bug free, take Quentin's suggestion about asking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Note that many returns in a function is viewed in some circles as just as bad as `goto`.

Answer (score -3):

As others have mentioned you can use a flag-ish variable. You can also use an exception as a way to break out of multiple loops.

You can also put the two inner loops into a separate function and use return.

But looking at the code why not change the algorithm? You should create a map from char to decrypted char so you can simply use:

```
newstr += map[code[i]];
```

Comment: Exceptions should be used in exceptional cases, not to break loops. Don't forget that they have a cost when thrown.